# Aluminum deoxidation gas

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox

I am new to chemistry. I am looking for a gas that would de-oxidise aluminium. 
Which gases would work for that and at what temperature?

Details: I need to sinter aluminium powder. But because the top layer of aluminium is oxidized when exposed to the atmosphere, I need to remove the oxide film before the sintering would work.

Thanks so much,

Sergey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> is *very* stable, powerful acids such as HF and chromic acid are used to remove the oxide surface. Since you're working with fine particles and wish to use a *gas*, rather than *liquid*, you'll need to consider what will become of the removed oxides. Gaseous HF would leave fluorides behind. Perhaps atomic hydrogen might work, but you'd have to remove the resultant water before the Al reoxidizes.

It is easier to prepare powdered aluminum *in an inert atmosphere* from bulk aluminum. There are a number of sites showing how to grind aluminum using anything from a file to a coffee grinder; you'd need to adapt this to run in argon, perhaps with a glove-box.

Sintering might be difficult, since Al is so soft that pore spaces would close.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.  At what temperature H would take O from Al?  Would other gases, like N or CO work?  If yes, at what temperature?  Should I use aluminum alloy instead of pure aluminum? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be easier to produce your own unoxidized Al powder than to remove the surface. The mention of *atomic* hydrogen was hypothetical rather than practical... you'd need to generate a hydrogen plasma, perhaps with RF, at low pressure and temperature so as not to melt the aluminum powder. As for sintering, an alloy would be better than pure Al, as it could be harder and resist compaction (I assume you want to sinter to a frit, rather than merely solidify).

Comment: I do want it to merely solidify, and compaction is desirable for my application.  Hydrogen plasma sounds too complicated, so I'll look into production of my own unoxidized Al powder. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the intent... you might be interested in this process of Al sintering, similar to injection molding of plastics: http://www.aluminiumindustry.org/en/powder-injection-moulding-aluminium.html .

Comment: Yes, it's somewhat similar, but they use a binder. Unfortunately they don't tell how they do the deoxidation.

Comment: It looks like Hydrogen will not displace aluminum even in plasma state because it's below aluminum in the activity series: http://antoine.frostburg.edu/chem/senese/101/redox/faq/activity-series.shtml